# How to get the information and sort, a subset of elements with only identifiers using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, subset

I'm new to XSLT and I can't resolve the following problem:

I have a xml file like this:

```
<root>
    <subset>
        <e id="A"></e>
        <e id="C"></e>
    </subset>

    <data>
        <info id="A" order="3" name="ANode"></info>
        <info id="B" order="4" name="BNode"></info>
        <info id="C" order="1" name="CNode"></info>
        <info id="D" order="2" name="DNode"></info>
    </data>
</root>
```

And I want to produce this:

```
<root>
    <newnode id="C" order="1" name="CNode"></newnode>
    <newnode id="A" order="3" name="ANode"></newnode>
</root>
```

As you can see the idea is to "complete" the subset of ids by retrieving the respective info, and sort them accordingly to their order specified on `<data>`.

Notice that `<data>` is supposed to have a lot of child nodes.

Also, I'm separating the nodes with the information on the `<data>` element from the subsets of ids, because I will have many subsets and I don't want to have repeated information "everywhere".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for a nice first question (complete, well-formulated, well-formatted, no bullshit). Many first-timer questions I see score 0 out of 4 for the mentioned criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also key off of the subset depending upon what else you may need to do with your actual data.

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="subset" match="e" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="//info[count(key('subset',@id)[1]) &gt; 0]">
        <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number" />
        <newnode id="{@id}" order="{@order}" name="{@name}" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cross-references ask for using keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="info" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="subset/e">
        <xsl:sort select="key('k1', @id)/@order" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e">
    <newnode id="{@id}" order="{key('k1', @id)/@order}" name="{key('k1', @id)/@name}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That should do for the input sample you presented.

Comment: +1 - The only thing I'd do differently is that in `<xsl:template match="e">` I'd store `key('k1', @id)` in a variable, since I need it twice. Not sure if it makes much actual difference, but calculating the same value twice goes against my principles. ;)